# Adding a 'x' and 'y' column using geometry coordinates

Tags: jupyter-notebook, coordinates

code and dataframe:

[image: code and dataframe]

I am would like to create an 'x' and 'y' column derived from the coordinates in the geometry column in my dataframe. Is there an easy way to do this in Jupyter notebook?

Comment: The code and dataframe link displays the picture of my code. Apologies, I am very new to coding

Comment: Please do not post images of code and data. Instead, please edit your question and add the code and data as text. This will make it easier for others to help you.